# How to Query for an event log details with a given event id?

Tags: c#, events

1. How to know whether a particular event (given event ID, time and node as inputs) is logged or not? [In this case, I know only one event will be logged]
2. If the event is logged, how do I get details like event description, Log-name etc..

for eg, I want to  query for an event under the node Applications and Services Logs > Microsoft > Windows > groupPolicy > Operational, and event id is 5315 and time is current time.

Answer (score 22, accepted):

There are a few new twists if your going to query events from the new style Windows EventLogs.

1. You will have to use the classes from the `System.Diagnostics.Eventing.Reader` namespace to read the new events.
2. Your query will be in Xpath form, so that time value is tricky, see msdn for the [`EventLogQuery` definition](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb399427.aspx).
3. Your program will run into access issues, be ready to impersonate a user that's included in the `EventReaders` AD group on the logging machine.

This sample shows some of the new access methods:

```
string eventID = "5312";
string LogSource = "Microsoft-Windows-GroupPolicy/Operational";  
string sQuery = "*[System/EventID=" + eventID + "]";

var elQuery = new EventLogQuery(LogSource, PathType.LogName, sQuery);
using (var elReader = new System.Diagnostics.Eventing.Reader.EventLogReader(elQuery))
{

    List<EventRecord> eventList = new List<EventRecord>();
    EventRecord eventInstance = elReader.ReadEvent();
    try
    {
        for (null != eventInstance; eventInstance = elReader.ReadEvent())
        {
            //Access event properties here:
            //eventInstance.LogName;
            //eventInstance.ProviderName;
            eventList.Add(eventInstance);
        }
    }
    finally
    {
        if (eventInstance != null)
            eventInstance.Dispose();
    }
}
```

Comment: how about getting event withing given dates?                             query = "*[System[" + 
         "(Provider/@Name=\"Microsoft Office 15 Alerts\") and " +
         //"(EventID=300) and " +
         "(TimeCreated/@SystemTime &gt;= \"" + t1 + "\") and " +
         "(TimeCreated/@SystemTime &lt;= \"" + t2 + "\")" +
                          "]]";                                                       I am getting query exception

Comment: What is the LogSource if I want to see Windows Logs/System?

Comment: `elReader` should be wrapped in a `using` statement

Comment: Should you be disposing each instance of eventInstance--not just the very last one?

Answer (score 11):

You could query the event log in question:

```
var sourceName = "MySource";
var el = new EventLog("Application");
var latestEntryTime = (from entry in el.Entries.Cast<EventLogEntry>()
                       where entry.Source == sourceName
                       && // put other where clauses here...
                       orderby entry.TimeWritten descending
                       select entry).First();
```

However, be warned that this approach is **slow**, since the `Entries` collection tends to be quite big.