# Get the computer's last wake time

Tags: .net, windows

I know I can get the time since the last boot using `Environment.TickCount`
But is it possible to get the last time a compute woke up from hibernation or sleep?

(Without using WMI please)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Try this command - use [Process](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.diagnostics.process.aspx) to fire it off - you'll need to parse the result

> cmd /k wevtutil qe System
>   /q:"*[System[Provider[@Name='Microsoft-Windows-Power-Troubleshooter']]]"
>   /rd:true /c:1 /f:text

Lifted from [here](http://www.xhroot.com/blog/2012/04/14/get-time-of-last-wake-from-sleep-in-windows7/) if you want more info...

Comment: Hey, is there a version that works for Windows 10? It works on Win7 but `Microsoft-Windows-Power-Troubleshooter` event doesn't seem to be broadcast, at least on my Win10 v.1709.

Comment: Oops, my bad. Tried it in the VM (VMWare Workstation.) It stopped reporting that event for some reason. But it works in a real hardware though.

Answer (score 0):

Although there's an answer above that provides the core query, here's a more fleshed out solution for anyone who decides they want something more complete.

```
private string getLastWakeInfo() {
    String args = @"qe System /q:"" *[System[Provider[@Name = 'Microsoft-Windows-Power-Troubleshooter']]]"" /rd:true /c:1 /f:xml";
    ProcessStartInfo psi = new ProcessStartInfo();
    psi.FileName = "wevtutil.exe";
    psi.UseShellExecute = false;
    psi.CreateNoWindow = true;
    psi.RedirectStandardOutput = true;
    psi.RedirectStandardError = true;
    psi.RedirectStandardInput = true;
    psi.Arguments = args;
    Process proc = Process.Start(psi);
    proc.WaitForExit(2000);
    String strOutput = proc.StandardOutput.ReadToEnd();
    return strOutput;
}
```

Usage:

```
private void button1_Click_2(object sender, EventArgs e) {
    String xml = getLastWakeInfo();
    XmlDocument doc = new XmlDocument();
    doc.LoadXml(xml);
    String path = "//*[local-name()='Event']/*[local-name()='EventData']/*[local-name()='Data'][@Name='WakeTime']";
    XmlNode root = doc.DocumentElement;
    XmlNode node = root.SelectSingleNode(path);
    MessageBox.Show(node.InnerText);
}
```

The following will be needed;

```
using System.Diagnostics;
using System.Runtime.InteropServices;
using System.Xml;
using System.Windows.Forms; // Needed only if you want to show the messagebox
```

In this example, I'm trying to find the PC wake time (as listed in `@Name='WakeTime'` - Change that to get the wake time or another individual value that's returned from the query). For example, if you want to know what woke up the PC, use `WakeSourceText` instead.

You'll definitely want to add some error checking, but this should achieve what you're looking for.

Comment: This can be done via a dotnet API as well similar to https://stackoverflow.com/a/2464118/468244

Answer (score -1):

According to [this page](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa373235%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) you'll have to listen for [PBT_APMRESUMEAUTOMATIC](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa372718%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) (and [PBT_APMRESUMESUSPEND](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa372720%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) if you want to know if a user was the 'cause' for the wakeup).

I think [Microsoft.Win32.SystemEvents](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.win32.systemevents.aspx) ([PowerModeChanged event](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.win32.systemevents.powermodechanged%28v=vs.85%29.aspx)) is the place to look but, without investigating any further, there might be [some issues](http://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/feedback/details/736387/systemevents-powermodechanged-appears-to-ignore-pbt-apmresumeautomatic#details).

[This page](http://www.pinvoke.net/default.aspx/user32/registerpowersettingnotification.html) might be interesting to get you started.

Comment: I don't want to allow my application to know if now's a wake up event, I want to be able to know *when* was the last wake up event