# query a custom eventlog searching for EventID

Tags: c#, .net, event-log

[DISCLAIMER]I'm pretty new to C# and I'm not a programmer![/DISCLAIMER]

I am following the example located here([C#: How to Query for an event log details with a given event id?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2462426/c-how-to-query-for-an-event-log-details-with-a-given-event-id)) to search for a given eventid in a custom eventlog.

The code in that example is:

```
string eventID = "5312";
string LogSource = "Microsoft-Windows-GroupPolicy/Operational";  
string sQuery = "*[System/EventID=" + eventID + "]";

var elQuery = new EventLogQuery(LogSource, PathType.LogName, sQuery);
var elReader = new System.Diagnostics.Eventing.Reader.EventLogReader(elQuery);

List<EventRecord> eventList = new List<EventRecord>();
for (EventRecord eventInstance = elReader.ReadEvent();
    null != eventInstance; eventInstance = elReader.ReadEvent())
{
    eventList.Add(eventInstance);
}
```

In my application I created an eventlog called "SMCLogs" and the LogSource is "SAM2_SMCLogs" so I changed to above code as follows:

```
string eventID = "330";
string LogSource = "SAM2_SMCLogs";  
string sQuery = "*[SMCLogs/EventID=" + eventID + "]";

var elQuery = new EventLogQuery(LogSource, PathType.LogName, sQuery);
var elReader = new System.Diagnostics.Eventing.Reader.EventLogReader(elQuery);

List<EventRecord> eventList = new List<EventRecord>();
for (EventRecord eventInstance = elReader.ReadEvent();
    null != eventInstance; eventInstance = elReader.ReadEvent())
{
    eventList.Add(eventInstance);
}
```

But I get the error: "**The specified channel could not be found. Check channel configuration**"

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1):

First you need to be sure that your event log and your event source exist.

Fast way to check this:

- Win + R
- type eventvwr.msc
- Right mouse button click on "Custom Views" folder in "Event Viewer" tree.
- Create Custom View...
- List item
- Select "By Log" radio button
- In dropdown list try to search your log under "Applications and Services Log"

If you see your log there -- ok, your log exists.

Now check if your source exists under your log, do the steps, but now choose "By source" instead of "By Log" radio button, and see if you can find your event source there.