# How could I retrieve the date time and user who last published a .NET MVC web application?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

I've been asked to show on the home page of a MVC .NET web application the windows user name and date when the application was last published. The application is published via Visual Studio 2012.

I'm clueless as to where to retrieve this data from.

Is this kind of information logged anywhere? (perhaps IIS?)

Comment: What method are you using to publish?  WebDeploy?  FileSystem?  FTP?

Comment: @ErikFunkenbusch WebDeploy

Comment: what solution is when deploying via `FileSystem` option ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

WebDeploy logs to the Windows EventLog, so you could use the [EvenLogQuery](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.diagnostics.eventing.reader.eventlogquery(v=vs.110).aspx) class to search for the event id you're looking for.  You should be able to search the event log to find this.  It will be under Applications > Microsoft Web Deploy on the deployed to server.

You'll also find an example of querying the EventLog here:

[C#: How to Query for an event log details with a given event id?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2462426/c-how-to-query-for-an-event-log-details-with-a-given-event-id)