# Accessing Application and Service logs with C#

Tags: c#

I was wondering if there is a way to reach the logs under the section named Application and Service Logs in the Event viewer utility in Windows. The thing is, I can read the entries under Windows Logs with the code below. I read the whole entry, and get the items with the necessary id, getting top 20 results. But I couldn't find anything on accessing the Application and Service logs section. Should I change the LogType in the EventLog constructor? Or is there a different method or class to access Application and Service logs? Trying `"Application"` as the `logType` variable doesnt work.

```
        string str = "";
        EventLog ev = new EventLog(logType, System.Environment.MachineName);
        int LastLogToShow = ev.Entries.Count;
        if (LastLogToShow <= 0)
            Console.WriteLine("No Event Logs in the Log :" + logType);

        int i;
        int k = 0;

        for (i = ev.Entries.Count - 1; i >= 0; i--)
        {
            EventLogEntry CurrentEntry = ev.Entries[i];
            if (CurrentEntry.EventID == id)
            {
                if (id == 1)
                {
                    str += "Son Açılma \n";
                    str += "Olay Zamanı: " + CurrentEntry.TimeGenerated.ToLongDateString() + " " + CurrentEntry.TimeGenerated.ToShortTimeString() + "\n";
                }

                else if (id == 42)
                {
                    str += "Son Kapatılma \n";
                    str += "Olay Zamanı: " + CurrentEntry.TimeGenerated.ToLongDateString() + " " + CurrentEntry.TimeGenerated.ToShortTimeString() + "\n";
                }
                else
                {
                    str += "Event type: " + CurrentEntry.EntryType.ToString() + "\n";
                    str += "Event Message: " + CurrentEntry.Message + CurrentEntry + "\n";
                    str += "Event : " + CurrentEntry.UserName + "\n" + "\n";
                    str += "Olay Zamanı: " + CurrentEntry.TimeGenerated.ToLongDateString() + " " + CurrentEntry.TimeGenerated.ToShortTimeString() + "\n";
                }
                k++;
            }
            if (k > 20)
                break;
        }
        ev.Close();
        return str;
```

What I am looking for is under

Application and Service Logs/

Microsoft/

Windows/

TerminalServices-RemoteConnectionManager/

Operational/

Event ID 1149

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I'm not sure you can access them using the [EventLog](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/System.Diagnostics.EventLog%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) class, or at least I couldn't figure out how. I did it using the [EventLogQuery](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.diagnostics.eventing.reader.eventlogquery%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) class instead.

I've provided an example below which I adapted from this post ([C#: How to Query for an event log details with a given event id?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2462426/c-how-to-query-for-an-event-log-details-with-a-given-event-id)), and should work for what you need:

```
using System.Diagnostics.Eventing.Reader;

string logType = "Microsoft-Windows-TerminalServices-RemoteConnectionManager/Operational";
string query = "*[System/EventID=1149]";

var elQuery = new EventLogQuery(logType, PathType.LogName, query);
var elReader = new EventLogReader(elQuery);

for (EventRecord eventInstance = elReader.ReadEvent(); eventInstance != null; eventInstance = elReader.ReadEvent())
{
      // .. do stuff here
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer, but the problem is, I am getting an InvalidOperationException error when the code reaches the end of the for block. I think that since the `readEvent()` reads the next value, it gets null or something? Oh and by the way, array gets filled with 42 event instances then I get the error

Comment: It works fine for me. No the for loop accounts for it and breaks when it encounters a null entry. What's the actual error it gives? Are you trying to modify the events in the loop?

Comment: It throws that error when you call the ReadEvent() method and there are no more events to read, are you doing that?

Comment: I can't figure out how to get the log description text with this. I don't see any description properties.

Comment: @user2924019 What do you mean by log description? Do you mean the log message? https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.diagnostics.eventlogentry.message?view=netframework-4.8#System_Diagnostics_EventLogEntry_Message

Comment: @IainWard I didn't know what I needed when I wrote that. What I needed was to get various properties of the event. I can do this with `Console.WriteLine(eventInstance.Properties[1].Value.ToString());`

Comment: Worked for me!  Thank you for the question and answer!