# VSTO how to log down the startup time of Add-in

Tags: outlook, vsto

see the [screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DkuHo.png)

I am developing an outlook Add-in. but the add-in is disabled by outlook randomly.

My question is how to log down the startup time of my Add-in and other Add-ins so I can investigate the reason.

Comment: There is no such log.
What does your addin do on startup (connection etc.)?

Comment: There is a connection for login. But it will be triggered only user click the btn on the ribbon.

Comment: I am not sure what you mean. So what does your addin do on start up?

Answer (score 0):

Outlook does this for you.

Go to **Event Viewer -> Windows Logs -> Application** and filter by:
Event ID: **45**
Source: **Outlook**

The log will contain a list of add-ins with some metadata and boot time.

If you need programmatic access (e.g. you need boot time somewhere in your app), refer to this link [How to Query for an event log details with a given event id?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2462426/c-how-to-query-for-an-event-log-details-with-a-given-event-id)
 Of course you will have to parse the event output to grab the data you need.