# What is the most efficient way to find an event in Windows event log programmatically using C#?

Tags: c#, .net

I'm dealing with some code which iterates through all the events like so:

```
EventLog el = new EventLog("Application", System.Environment.MachineName);
for (i = 0; i < el.Entries.Count; i++)
{
    EventLogEntry CurrentEntry = el.Entries[i];
    // Rest of the logic
}
```

This however is extremely inefficient taking over 4 seconds for ~30000 events.

Is there a faster way?

Comment: what's the other logic...might be important

Comment: Have you tried `System.Diagnostics.Eventing.Reader.EventLogReader`?

Comment: Calling `Entries.Count` seems to cause a full query of the event log. If you do `foreach` you avoid this and the code runs twice as fast.

Comment: @Enigmativity Thre EventLogEntryCollection cannot be iterated directly with a foreach, however I did test the code with getting the enumerator and then using movenext. Same result, it did not improve on the time a significant amount (a few seconds)

Comment: @Ctznkane525 I thought so too, but having tested without it I can assure you that it is not what's causing the inefficiency.

Comment: do you have a coded filter of the items are are processing...i assume you dont want ALL the records - see this if you dont really want the whole collection - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2462426/c-how-to-query-for-an-event-log-details-with-a-given-event-id

Comment: @Dipen - Call `.Cast<EventLogEntry>()` on the entries and you can use `foreach`.